# Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) におけるhtmlファイルのコメントの色の変更方法

Tags: spring

現在Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse) を用いて開発業務を行っていますが、
htmlファイルのコメントの色がグレーで設定されておりダークモードと相性が悪いため
変更したいのですがやり方がわかりません。

設定>一般>色とフォント
でjavaファイル等の文字色を変更できることは
確認済みですがhtmlファイルの設定に当たるものが見当たらないため
ご教示いただきたいです。

Comment: 現在、[Spring Tool Suite(STS)](https://spring.io/tools)([GitHubリポジトリリンク](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4))という語が指すものは、Eclipse, VSCode, etc にSpring拡張が組み込まれたものの総称かと思います。これらのうちのどれを指しているのかも明示した方が良いかと考えます。

Comment: @yukihaneありがとうございます。修正いたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htmlファイルはデフォルトだと "HTML Editor" で開く設定になっていますが、このエディタの色設定は
Web > HTML Files > Editor > Syntax Coloring
にあります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ございませんご教示いただいたやり方で解決いたしました！ありがとうございました！